# How to make Bash not wait for EOF?

Tags: bash, keyboard, binary, file-transfer

So I made a simple Bash script that can use your keyboard LEDs (numlock and capslock) to transmit data (inspired by LTT from their "Do NOT Plug This USB In! – Hak5 Rubber Ducky" video). This is the script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /dev/stdin | perl -lpe '$_=unpack"B*"' | sed 's/./\ &/g'`
 do export E=`expr $E + 1`
 echo "Bit number $E has a value of $i"
 if (( $i == 0 ))
  then
  xdotool key Caps_Lock
  sleep 0.1
  xdotool key Caps_Lock
 else
  xdotool key Num_Lock
  sleep 0.1
  xdotool key Num_Lock
fi
done
```

It does something different, and that is have the LEDs for the keyboard common low instead of common high (meaning the LEDs are off longer compared to Linus' video). However, it has a flaw. It waits until an EOF from stdin, which isn't what I'd like. I'd like it to act like minimodem, reading data while it's being written to stdin (well, after a newline, at least). Is there a way I can do this without:

1. changing programming languages, and
2. without breaking the entire script?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Since you're already using perl for part of the job, probably the easiest method is to do the entire thing in perl, with the [Term::Readkey](https://metacpan.org/release/TermReadKey) module.   For example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use Term::ReadKey;

# trap INT so we can reset the terminal on ^C
$SIG{INT} = sub { exit };

ReadMode 3;

while ($_ = ReadKey 0) {

  last if m/\cD/;

  @bits = split //, unpack "B*";

  for my $i (0..$#bits) {
    print "Bit number $i has a value of $bits[$i]";
    if ($bits[$i] == 0) {
      system("xdotool key Caps_Lock; sleep 0.1; xdotool key Caps_Lock");
    } else {
      system("xdotool key Num_Lock; sleep 0.1; xdotool key Num_Lock");
    };
  };
};

END {
  ReadMode 0;
};
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to install a module from CPAN, you can use `stty` as described in `perldoc -f getc` to make `getc` read a single character at a time. Or use the `setattr()` function from the POSIX module (which is included with perl) instead of running `stty`.

However, since you want to do it in bash (and cat & perl & sed), you could try something based on this:

1. First, realise that you never need to use `cat` to pipe data into a program which can already read from stdin (as perl and sed and almost everything else can do).
2. Then realise that whenever you're piping perl's output into sed, you're probably doing it wrong and can do whatever you're doing in sed in the perl script instead. perl also has a s/// operator, just like sed.
3. Remember that bash has arrays, and you can read the output of a program into an array with the bash `mapfile` built-in and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).

and

4. bash can read a single character at a time with `read -n 1`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -n 1 char ; do

  case "$char" in
    $'\004') break ;; # Ctrl-D
  esac

  # This uses perl to print each bit separated by a newline. we could do it with s/// in perl,
  # but here i'm using split and join. the output from perl is read into bash array $bits.
  mapfile -t bits < <(printf '%s' "$char" | perl -lne 'print join("\n", split //, unpack"B*")')

  # that expr stuff is incredibly ugly. and decades obsolete for shell arithmetic.
  # i'm going to use let instead because I also find (( i=i+1 )) to be incredibly ugly. 
  count=0
  for i in "${bits[@]}" ; do
    let count+=1
    echo "Bit number $count has a value of $i"
    if [ "$i" -eq 0 ] ; then
      xdotool key Caps_Lock
      sleep 0.1
      xdotool key Caps_Lock
    else
      xdotool key Num_Lock
      sleep 0.1
      xdotool key Num_Lock
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: This works @cas, but now it doesn't recognize a ^D (ctrl+d) when writing directly to it... Other than that, works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I added a case statement to check if $char is ^D and break out of the loop if it is.  Could have used `if`, but case is more convenient if you need to handle other characters differently.   One key I couldn't figure out how to handle in the bash script was enter, probably because it marks the EOL, probably need to set IFS to something.   enter works in the perl  version.

Comment: I noticed this yesterday but couldn't post it due to thanksgiving with the family, but it won't recognize spaces and some other (more obscure) characters. Found that out while trying to make it read out a 700-byte PNG file.

Comment: yeah, that'll be the IFS problem I mentioned.  Use the perl version instead.  bash isn't a real programming language, it's a command-line interpreter that can read commands from a file.  You could change the while read line to `while IFS=$'\000' read -r -n 1 char ; do` and that would make it "work" for all keystrokes **except** enter and Ctrl-@, which isn't really a solution, it just shifts the problem.

Comment: So I built a decoder (in bash, of course - it's the only language i know other than TI-82 BASIC) for it, but while it can read spaces it cannot read null bytes... Would you like me to update my question with the decoder included?

Comment: re: updating the question - not really. i have no compelling desire to spend more time on getting bash to do things that bash is terrible at doing.  use the right tool for the job.  bash (or any shell) is precisely the wrong tool. perl is one of the many right tools.

Comment: BTW, I was wrong - setting IFS to NUL doesn't work for more than just ^@ and ^M.  it doesn't work for several other control chars too - ^J, ^K, ^Q, ^S and probably others.  and, of course, ^C exits, ^D is EOF, and ^Z suspends the script (could trap some of those - but don't waste your effort on bash, use perl or python or anything other than a shell).